# Import OpenCV in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-datalab

How to import OpenCV in GCP? I'm using Google Datalab here.

It looks like I can install the package:

```
!pip install opencv-python

Collecting opencv-python
Downloading opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.7MB)
100% |################################| 6.7MB 98kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.1 in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from opencv-python)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-3.2.0.7
```

But after I import cv2, I get an error

```
import cv2

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py in <module>()
  5 os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  6 
----> 7 from . import cv2
  8 sys.modules['cv2'] = cv2

ImportError: libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i succeeded in the next step.

let's try this ♥

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get -y upgrade
!pip install opencv-python
!apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev -y
```

Comment: Didn't work for me: "E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated"

Comment: This works, you have to use --allow-unauthenticated; the upgrade isn't necessarily required:

!pip install --upgrade pip && pip install opencv-python
!apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libgtk2.0-dev

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me with:
!apt-get install python-opencv -y --allow-unauthenticated

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining how your code resolves the problem?